# Chaining Android activities : install after uninstallation

Tags: android, android-activity, installation

I want to uninstall a particular APK and after that I need to install another APK file. However, my app shows activity to uninstall and install simultaneously, not one after another. How can I solve this issue? I want the user to uninstall the apk and only after that install the new apk. Thank you so much.

Following is the code I tried.

```
public void uninstallAndInstall(View view) {

 /* code to uninstall an app */



 try
    {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:"+ applicationPackageName));
        startActivity(intent);

     /* Code to install an app*/

       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
       intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(sdcard,"Android/data/com.mycompany.android.games/temp/temp.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
       intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       context.startActivity(intent);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: instead of startActivity you should use startActivityForResult and handle the next intent within that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try waiting until [the `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED` broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED) arrives for the package you are requesting that the user uninstall, before you start the installation process of the next package.

Also, bear in mind that the user is not obligated to accept your uninstall request.

Comment: I tried to add that permission to manifest file. It says only system apps can have this permission.

Comment: @aMa: It is not a permission. It is an `Intent` action that is broadcast when a package is removed. You cannot *send* the broadcast unless you are a system app.